# Time-Independent Gravitational Equation?

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, cosmology, time

Is it possible to calculate gravitational induced position change without requiring the use of time (and therefore, acceleration) anywhere in the equation?

If such an equation were to be discovered, would it be significant to cosmology/physics?

Comment: How could you describe a change in position without relating it to time?  Doing so would mean that the change in position is instantaneous, which would violate many of the foundations our current theories are based on.

Comment: Not necessarily saying that the position change wouldn't take "time" to occur, but that you could calculate it without needing time in the equation. For example, what if I could calculate the position of an object simply based on a reading of its Doppler shift (not a Doppler shift over time, but just an absolute Doppler shift reading).

Comment: Hmm - still not exactly sure what you're getting at.  You can definitely use Doppler shifts to measure velocity and thus instead of using velocity use Doppler shifts.  It's just a different unit, in a sense, for measuring position change relative to time (note that frequency has units of 1/time)

Comment: But velocity requires time in the equation— ie, you need to know over what time that doppler shift occurred in order to calculate velocity. Here's what I'm getting at: Let's say I have two measurements of the wavelength of a star taken at two different points in "time" but nothing to tell me the time period over which those two measurements were taken.

Comment: continuing.... Would I be able to calculate the distance traveled without knowing the time period between when those two measurements were taken?

Comment: The reason this interests me is that if we were able to describe and calculate gravitational effects without the need for "time" wouldn't it negate our need to use special-relativity? And I'm not saying time doesn't exist, but that it may be inconsequential to our understanding of gravity, matter, forces, etc.

Comment: No, you would be able to infer the change in velocity but you cannot determine a distance traveled purely by knowing a change in velocity.  Just consider a car that accelerates from 0mph to 60mph.  The distance traveled will be different depending on how fast the car accelerates, but you don't know how fast; therefore you can't know the distance traveled. (Also note that you'd have to assume constant acceleration here, furthermore showing that you don't have enough information)

Comment: mcFreid, would you be willing to look at a paper my father has been developing on this subject, and let me know what you think? It's a quick read... https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/819120/APL%20Gravity%20Paper.pdf

Comment: I took a quick look at the paper.  It states an equation without any derivation.  It states that the equation accurately describes experiment without a single example.  Furthermore the units of equation (1) don't equate due to the factor $\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: In terms of examples, I know it was confirmed on some empirical data gathered from astronomical surveys done on galaxy rotation, but I'll need to ask him to send me the actual source of the data and show some examples. As for 1/m, I agree the units don't match up, but the results of the equation (in terms of pure numerical quantities) do match with empirical data measurements (in meters)...

Comment: ...  This has resulted in some interesting questions we've asked ourselves like: Why is delta-r inversely proportional to mass? What is the physical inverse of mass (ie does it even make sense to describe it with conventional units)? Is 1/m real or contrived?

Comment: mcFreid, here is a version with an example proof: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/819120/JMP%201.2.pdf

Comment: First, the results in Table 4 are incorrect to the point where it looks fraudulent.  You can quickly do the calculation just by looking at the orders of magnitudes of the input numbers and you'll find that the integer numbers (1,2,3,4,etc...) are off by a few orders of magnitude.  Second, the values in table 3 seem incredibly contrived.  For example, look at the time values and you'll see them input in a nonlinear manner just to make the delta H values whole integers.  If you want to compare two equations you should plot them instead of comparing a few nicely selected numbs (which fail anyway)

Comment: mcFreid, are you serious? The numbers is table 4 are calculated just fine— it's a simple equation, do you want me to show the work for you? That's just lazy. Also your point about table 3 doesn't make any sense either. He chose distance as the independent variable in the simulated values in table 3— okay go ahead and make time the independent variable so you can get nice round numbers there, it doesn't change a thing. I do agree a graph would be nice. But does that change anything? The numbers line up very nicely...

Comment: Alpha - for sanity check I calculated $\delta r$ for rows #2 and #3 of Table 4 exactly (not just looking at orders of magnitude).  I calculated $\delta r =  0.00887245$ for row #2 and $\delta r = 0.0177449$ for row #3.  As you can see, both answers are orders of magnitudes away from the answers written as expected with my previous quick estimation.  I'd be happy to screenshot my calculation, but like you mentioned it's fairly trivial.

Comment: mcFried, I completely apologize for calling BS on your calculations and acting like a jerk— you were right and thank you for catching the error. The wrong number for m2 got pasted in the document from the spreadsheet. m2 should be 5.97420E+24 not 6.7334106E+26— i.e. values in   tables 3 and 4 are calculated with 5.97420E+24 but the constant was improperly shown as 6.7334106E+26 in Table 1. If you replace 5.97420E+24 for m2 in your calculations, do you get the proper numbers?

Comment: BTW, I can send you the spreadsheet if you're interested in looking it over.